# Создание архивов по SSH

Tags: .htaccess, ssh, tar

Необходимо создать архив по SSH на удаленном сервере. Стандартная команда tar не включает в архив файлы .htaccess

```
tar -czvf archname.tar.gz *
```

Как сделать, чтобы в архив были включены все без исключения файлы, **в том числе и .htaccess**?

Answer (score 4):

Это особенность не ssh или tar, а unix-shell, который вместо * подставляет имена файлов в текущем каталоге, при этом пропускает все начинающиеся на точку. Начальную точку надо указывать явно.

```
tar -czvf archname.tar.gz * .??*
```

(так будут добавлены ещё имена начинающиеся с точки и длиной не менее 3х символов.Если написать .* , будут добавлены ещё каталоги . и .. , а это не нужно.)

Либо указывайте имя каталога, а не файлов в нём:

```
tar -czvf archname.tar.gz .
```

В таком случае tar может попытаться добавить archname.tar.gz сам в себя и выдаст ошибку,чтобы его не нервировать, разместите архив в родительском каталоге:

```
tar -czvf ../archname.tar.gz .
```

Comment: Ты делаешь не как хакир) ls -A | xargs tar -czvf tar.tar.gz

Comment: эээ так чревато ошибками

Comment: Да я 100 раз так делал) Димон)

Comment: 1. Если файлов слишком много, xargs может вызывать команду несколько раз, чтобы не переполнить ограничение системы на количество аргументов в командной строке, в архив попадут только файлы из последней группы.2. Если имя файла содержит пробел, он не попадёт в архив (конечно юзер сам себе злобный буратино, раз так файлы называет)

Comment: Действительно, вы правы! Насчет кол-ва действительно фича.